# Create in-memory sqlite database with database name in python

Tags: python, sqlite, connection-string, in-memory-database

I want to create multiple in-memory sqlite databases with names in python.

In sqlite command line it's possible to do that with this syntax:

```
':memory:' AS database_name
```

but when using it in python conenction strings like this:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("':memory:' AS database_name")
```

get error.

My problem is how can we create multiple in memory databases with names for accessing them.

How we could do that in python?

Answer (score 6):

The AS clause works only with the [ATTACH statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html), but not for the main database (which is always named `main`).

And the identify of a database comes from its *file name*, so changing the database name would not help anyway.

To use a custom "file" name for an in-memory database, use a [URI file name](http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html) with the `mode` parameter:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("file:blah?mode=memory", uri=True)
```

But to attach another in-memory database with a custom database name to the same connection, just execute ATTACH normally:

```
conn.execute("ATTACH ':memory:' AS db2")
```

Comment: would you show me an example that is needed for my purpose?