# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown database "mydb"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a problem to use flask_alchemy for my unit test function

In the production environment I use a postgresql database

```
"SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI": "postgresql://login:passwd@dburl:1234/mydatabase",
```

To work with the postgresql schema, in my entity definition i declare a  _*table_args* to specify a schema

```
    class MyTable(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'my_tablename'
        __table_args__ = {'schema': 'mydbschema'}
    
        my_id = Column('my_id', Date, primary_key=True)

....
```

But in my unittest i would like to use a memory database

```
"SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI": "sqlite://",
```

When i run my function i have this error :

```
E   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown database "mydbschema"
```

Somebody knows a workarround in this case ?

Comment: Based on [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#uri-connections) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45459634/2144390) you could try `e = create_engine("sqlite:///file:mydbschema?mode=memory&uri=true")`

Comment: @GordThompson thank you for the link I tried but the problem is SQLLITE does not support schema, i find a workarround with a ternary expression :)

Comment: I'm not sure that it would be a comprehensive workaround, but [this](https://pastebin.com/bk61xiXD) seems to avoid the 'unknown database "mydbschema"' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that OP found a workaround (though, I'm not sure how it works), but for those who still searching for proper solution - you need to use [ATTACH DATABASE statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) in order to select specific schema, for example if you are using `pytest` you can use following fixture to create test's setup:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

@pytest.fixture
def setup_db():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute('ATTACH DATABASE \':memory:\' AS mydbschema;')
        yield conn
```

Of course, you can define fixture scope by your needs.

Similarly, you can use [DETACH DATABASE statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_detach.html) to detach and dissociate a named database from a database connection (if necessary), which will destroy DB in the case of in-memory databases.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround ...

```
class MyTable(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'my_tablename'
        __table_args__ = {'schema': 'mydbschema'}
    
        my_id = Column('my_id', Date, primary_key=True) if os.environ.get('TESTVAR') is None else {}

....
```

Comment: What do you mean by doing this ? I face the same kind of problem, for the same purpose.

Comment: it looks like you're building test functionality into your source code. Don't do that